# cannot change title text color in jquery fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How can I change the color of the title in fullcalendar ?

I can change the background color in css:

```
.fc-header-title {
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

but setting the color has no effect.

```
.fc-header-title {
    color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the element style in Chrome does change the color, so it is likely another css selector is more specific.

Try

```
.fc-header-title h2 {
    color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

I cannot find any CSS on the full calendar sample site that actually sets the h2 color, so it appears to be using the browser default. If that is the case you must have your own `h2` style set somewhere, which is more specific than using the class selector `.fc-header-title`. in any case the more specific selector `.fc-header-title h2` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
.fc-header-title {
    color:#CCCCCC !important;
}
```

Comment: While that would also likely work, using `!important` is generally considered a "bad thing" to do, except in emergencies, as it also overrides any subsequent styling added afterwards. Basically a maintenance nightmare once you let them creep into your CSS :)